# React state is undefined when setting it with a hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and I am trying to set a state from a selection in a dropdown box, but my state remains undefined.

This is the array of objects that I am using for the dropdown (categorias.js):

```
export const categorias_array = [
{
  key: 1,
  text: "Primera",
  value: "1"
},
{
  key: 3,
  text: "Tercera",
  value: "3" 
},
{
  key: 4,
  text: "Cuarta",
  value: "4" 
},
{
  key: 5,
  text: "Quinta",
  value: "5" 
},
{
  key: 6,
  text: "Sexta",
  value: "6" 
},
{
  key: 7,
  text: "Septima",
  value: "7" 
}
];
```

And this is my code:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Select } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { lista_jugadores } from './jsons/lista_jugadores'
import { categorias_array } from './jsons/categorias'

export default () => {

  const[categoria, setCategoria] = useState(categorias_array[0].key);


  return(
    <div>
      <Dropdown placeholder="Seleccionar divisional" options={categorias_array} value={categoria} onChange={ (e) => setCategoria(e.target.value) }/>
      <h1>Categoria:{categoria}</h1> 
    </div>
    
  );
```

I just want to ensure that in this early stage the state is set visualizing it in h1 but is not working, it remains undefined. Ideally, I would like that my state is directly one of the objects of the array categories, however, I will be able to work if it is just the value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is something missing very important. `export default YourComponentName = () => {` Where is your component name?

Comment: Which state is undefined?

Comment: modified the question, categoria state remains undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the second parameter of the change handler to get the selected id.

Define your handleChange like this,

```
 onChange={ (e, data) => setCategoria(data.value) }
```

Complete Code:-

```
  const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState(categorias_array[0].key);

  const handleChange = (e, data) => {
    // data.value will give the selected id
    console.log(data.value);
    setCategoria(data.value);
  };
      return (
        <div>
          <Dropdown
            placeholder="Seleccionar divisional"
            options={categorias_array}
            value={categoria}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <h1>Categoria:{categoria}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Working Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-paper-1cvo4?file=/src/App.js:729-1154